# splash screen is not showing on android

Tags: android, cordova, build

i have really searched about the problem but didn't find the correct solution that's why again here..

i have a Ionic+ Cordova project  i want to show Splash Screen on android. project include a
res folder and inside that a drawable folder where i have placed my screen.png which i want to show.
but the problem is the file is not showing .
what is the problem how to show

i have include below line of code in config.xml which is inside of root folder

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="20000" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

and my splash screen is here

```
platforms/android/res/drawable/screen.png
```

before app load a black than white backgound shows..

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the splashscreen plugin in order to use it.
You can write the preferences in the config.xml, but I would recommand to do use the platform tag. Also make sure that you provide a splashscreen for each resolution in the drawables folder

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1500" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the SplashScreen to AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: The splash screen is activity? If it is, then you must to add it to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i have only a png img

Comment: Why do not you add a splash Screen?